# constant defined in the Color class - Myprogramminglab

Tags: java, colors, constants

I can't figure this one out:

> ```
> > Given g, a reference to a Graphics object, use a constant defined in
> > the Color class to write a statement that arranges for the next drawn
> > rectangle to be red:
> ```

Anybody an idea? It is for Myprogramminglab

I thought of:

```
g.setColor(Color.red); 
g.drawRect (10, 10, 200, 200);
```

or something like that, but doesn't work. Tried everything I could imagine.

Thanks

EDIT

Last question on Myprogramminglab was like this:

> ```
> > Write the invocation (method name with arguments) needed to display
> > the outline of a square whose sides are 60 pixels and whose top right
> > corner is located at (100,200).
> ```

Answer was:

```
drawRect(40,200,60,60)
```

So I don't get any more or less information about what I need to do and the answers are not like building entire scripts. So I really don't have a clue. In the book Java Solutions there are also no information about my problem I am having now.

Comment: Your code seems correct, given working `Graphics` object it should work. Maybe post a http://sscce.org so we can tell you what exactly is not working.

Comment: I have no clue what to do. I have edited my question a little bit.

Comment: If it's all you need to do, your answer should be perfectly fine. If it doesn't work (I gather you're typing this code into some kind of a web form or teacher-provided environment)? If so, look for typographical glitches in environment, try to delete space after `drawRect` or after commas. Take it to your teacher, this code does what it should do.

Comment: Another idea, try `Color.RED` instead of `Color.red`. Java allows both, the former is preferred and may in fact be required by your environment.

Comment: omg... it was `g.setColor(Color.red);` `g.setColor(Color.RED);` also works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
g.setColor(Color.red);
```

and

```
g.setColor(Color.RED);
```

both work.

Comment: @Baz I guess my comment wasn't properly written. Will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your code inside a [paintComponent(Graphics g)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method, overridden from a JComponent class (like JPanel).

---- Edit ----

Here is some code to give you some clues:

```
public class MyHomeworkClass extends JPanel {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(40,200,60,60);
    }
}
```

Then just add this panel to a Frame to show it.

Comment: Yes maybe so, but it will not work. I have edited my question a little bit

Comment: I found it out: it was `g.setColor(Color.red);` `g.setColor(Color.RED);` also works., btw, it does not need any scripts. Thanks anyway